# css-loader css modules rules of nested component

Tags: reactjs, webpack, sass, css-loader, css-modules

Lets say I use scss modules in the following way

`A.jsx`:

```
import styles from './A.module.scss';
import B from '../B/B.jsx';

const A = props => {
    return <div className={styles.a}>
         <B/>
    </div>;
};

export default A;
```

`B.jsx`:

```
import './B.scss';

const B = props => {
    return <div className="b">
    </div>;
};

export default B;
```

and inside `A.module.scss` I override B's css rules as follows:

```
.a {
 .b {
    width: 500;
    height: 500;
    background-color: red;
 }
}
```

then the styles I override for the `B` instance inside `A` are not passes to it, obviously because it's using css modules. How can I make the css rules of `B` applies only in `A` and not globally?

I thought maybe I have to pass custom `className` props for every component I want to achieve this, so for this instance pass custom `className` prop to `B` and pass it like so:

```
<B className={styles.b}/>
```

and in `B.jsx` just apply the custom class to the component.
Not my favourite solution, would rather not adding custom class but use just custom selector `.a .b` as this defines the relationship of every `B` which is under `A` I want to target, but I'm wondering if there's a simpler solution like I'm looking for?

Also I'm not sure the `className` prop is a viable solution for when `B` has several nodes nested in it and I'm trying to target a nested node inside it with my css rules. I can't just have for every component I have a `className` prop for every node in it.

Here's an example illustrating this situation:

`B.jsx`:

```
import './B.scss';

const B = props => {
    return <div className="b">
        <div className"b-inner1">
            <div className"b-inner2">
                <div className"b-inner3">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>;
};

export default B;
```

Here for example I wish to style the node with the `className` `b-inner3` which might be just a node that is there for helping with the basic layout of the `B`'s component and I do not wish to be able users of this component pass `className` to this node.

Comment: passing a `class` is the idiomatic way in this case (IMO)

Comment: and what if `B` is a custom library not enabling an option of passing `className` or `style` properties?

Comment: Then you can't style it "gracefully". you'll need to create a selector (a global one) based on the library's html and hope it won't change. (not mentioning open source contributions and forks, but obviously an option)

Comment: Remember, style and class names are part of the components API, not respecting these props means its not part of this library API. Same as if you can't pass a callback prop for some event that happens inside a library if the library isn't doing anything with it

Comment: unfortunately there're many libraries that don't let you pass className or style for a nested node.
Another situation might be is that `B` is not a library it's inside my code base and `B` consist of several nested nodes. How can I apply the styles I wish for a nested node inside `B` without passing multiple `className` props for each node?

Comment: @Sagivb.g I've edited my op to illustrate my situation better. Would appreciate if you could take a look!

Answer (score 0):

Each component (like any other function) has some abstractions over implementation details, it also has an API, this API is a contract between you and the consumer of your component.
If you are not exposing a `className` or `style` prop, that means you are basically saying "this component will not guaranty to always keep the same structure or public class names in the DOM". If anyone will override your classes, he/she are taking a risk and may face a breaking change.

If you do want to give the consumers the ability to override or add styling, you have 2 (or 3) main options as i see it:

1. Accept `style` and `className` props for each node you want to allow
   styling:

   ```
   const MyComponent = (props) => (
       <div className={`${styles.myStyle1} ${props.publicStyle1}`}>
           <div className={`${styles.myStyle2} ${props.publicStyle2}`}>
               <button
                   className={`${styles.button}
                   ${props.publicStyleButton}`}
               >
                   Click Me
               </button>
           </div>
       </div>
   );
   ```

   Yes, this can get messy and may look like a confusing API to
   consume and maintain.
2. Expose hardcoded class names:

   ```
   const MyComponent = (props) => (
       <div className={`${styles.myStyle1} public-style-1`}>
           <div className={`${styles.myStyle2} public-style-2`}>
               <button
                   className={`${styles.button} public-style-button`}
               >
                   Click Me
               </button>
           </div>
       </div>
   );
   ```

   This way, your contract says you will always keep those public class names (or a breaking change version)
3. Another approach which is not directly related to styling, usually
   referred as "Compound Components", you can mix it with one of
   the approaches above:

   ```
   const MyButton = ({ text, onClick, ...rest }) => (
       <button
           onClick={onClick}
           className={`${styles.button}`}
           {...rest}
       >
           {text}
       </button>
   )

   const MyComponent = (props) => (
       <div className={`${styles.myStyle1} public-style-1`}>
           {children}
       </div>
   );

   MyComponent.Button = MyButton;


   /* usage... */

   <MyComponent>
       <MyComponent.Button
           text="Click Me"
           className="consumer-class"
           style={{color: 'green'}}
       />
   </MyComponent>
   ```

   This will let you break your component into smaller pieces and give
   more control to your consumers.

Comment: Option 3 & 2 are not really ideal for me because I use css modules primarily to reduce bundle size. I guess I'll have to stick with option 1 as giving a prop className/style for each prop.
But what can I do if I have a `list` component and and `item` component. Each have their own css module styles but `list` css module also contains styles for each item to have `margin-bottom` for example. I put it in the css module of `item` but it doesn't make sense since you want this property only inside the list, I can also do selector such ass `.list > div` if I know the `item` tag but that's not ideal